# receiving serial port data in a while loop within startbutton_Click() function

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have created a wpf from and in it each time I get two byte from serial port and find the difference between them and then in a while loop I show the difference by a textbox:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    SerialPort port;
    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        port = new SerialPort("COM3");
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port.Open();
        try
        {
            if (!port.IsOpen)
                throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("port is not open!!");
        }
        while (port.IsOpen)
        {
            var b1 = port.ReadByte();
            var b2 = port.ReadByte();
            double t1 = b1 * 1e-9;
            double t2 = b2 * 1e-9; ;
            var dift = t2 - t1;
            if (dift == 0)
            {
                this.SpeedTextBox.Text = "0";
                continue;
            }
            this.SpeedTextBox.Text = dift;
        }
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (port != null)
        {
            if (port.IsOpen) port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I execute it and click on StartButton the form will be stoped working.I know that program receives data( I tested it with another simple program) . but I don't know what goes wrong here!!

can anyone help me?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadByte() is a blocking method, it won't return until a byte was received.  This is why SerialPort has the DataReceived event.

First use another program like Hyperterminal or Putty to test the connection and eliminate simple mistakes like bad wiring, picking the wrong port number or baud rate and getting the Parity, DataBits and StopBits settings wrong.  Which you don't set so there are non-zero odds that you'll get framing errors.  You must implement the ErrorReceived event to ensure these kind of errors do not go unobserved and leave you mystified why it doesn't work.

If you don't use DataReceived then it is also important that you use the ReadTimeout property to ensure your program doesn't hang forever without any way to diagnose the cause if there's something wrong with the connection.  Be prepared to catch the TimeoutException.

SysInternals' PortMon is a very useful utility to compare good vs bad, it shows you exactly what's going on inside the serial port driver.  Beware however that it doesn't work on a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Hans has covered the serial port cases, but another reason why your program will lock up is that your click handler uses an infinite wait loop. The way Windows applications work is that they have a main loop that gets messages (like click events) from a queue. For each message, your event handler is called, and it is only when your event handler returns control to the main loop that it can process the next message (e.g. to redraw your window and show the new text you have set on your control). So you can't use a long loop or blocking calls in your event handler if you want your program to remain responsive to user input.

Comment: Good answer, but you forgot to mention how you solve this problem.

Comment: true. I was expecting someone else to offer a description of asynchronous comms using BeginRead() as it's difficult for me to post correct code samples from memory via my phone.Exercise for the reader: investigate SerialPort.BeginRead()